# Transpose first row into column and simplify repeating columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Despite spending half the day on Stack Overflow, I have not found a solution. Working in python 3.9.0, I need to clean a dataframe. The first row should be transposed into a column, the second row needs to be made a header, and the repeating columns ('political_rights', 'civil_liberties, 'status') need to be simplified into only 3 columns. This can be done by making the values in the column "country" repeat for each year. Whenever I accomplish one thing, I mess up another so any help/advice is deeply appreciated!

**Simiplified version of current dataframe (actual df: 207 rows × 148 columns):**

```
df_bad = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['years', 'country', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra'],
                       'col2': [1972, 'political_rights', 4, 7, 6, 4], 
                       'col3': [1972, 'civil_liberties', 5, 7, 6, 3],
                       'col4': [1972, 'status', 'PF', 'NF', 'NF', 'NF'],
                       'col5': [1973, 'political_rights', 7, 7, 6, 4],
                       'col6': [1973, 'civil_liberties', 6, 7, 6, 4],
                       'col7': [1973, 'status', 'NF', 'NF', 'NF', 'PF']})
```

**Simiplified version of desired dataframe (future df: 10250 rows × 5 columns):**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Afghanistan',  'Albania', 'Algeria'],
                   'years': [1972, 1972, 1972, 1973, 1973, 1973], 
                   'political_rights': [4, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6],
                   'civil_liberties': [5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6],
                   'status': ['PF', 'NF', 'NF', 'NF', 'NF', 'NF']})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
s = df_bad.T
s.columns = s.loc['col1']
s = s.drop('col1').set_index(['years', 'country'])
s = s.stack().rename_axis(['years', None, 'country'])
s = s.unstack(1).reset_index()
```

### Explained

Transpose the dataframe

```
          0                 1            2        3        4        5
col1  years           country  Afghanistan  Albania  Algeria  Andorra
col2   1972  political_rights            4        7        6        4
col3   1972   civil_liberties            5        7        6        3
col4   1972            status           PF       NF       NF       NF
col5   1973  political_rights            7        7        6        4
col6   1973   civil_liberties            6        7        6        4
col7   1973            status           NF       NF       NF       PF
```

Set the columns to `col1` values, then `drop` `col1` and set the index to `years` and `country`

```
col1                   Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra
years country                                             
1972  political_rights           4       7       6       4
      civil_liberties            5       7       6       3
      status                    PF      NF      NF      NF
1973  political_rights           7       7       6       4
      civil_liberties            6       7       6       4
      status                    NF      NF      NF      PF
```

`Stack` the dataframe to reshape into multiindex series then rename axis

```
years                    country    
1972   political_rights  Afghanistan     4
                         Albania         7
                         Algeria         6
                         Andorra         4
       civil_liberties   Afghanistan     5
                         Albania         7
                         Algeria         6
                         Andorra         3
       status            Afghanistan    PF
                         Albania        NF
                         Algeria        NF
                         Andorra        NF
1973   political_rights  Afghanistan     7
                         Albania         7
                         Algeria         6
                         Andorra         4
       civil_liberties   Afghanistan     6
                         Albania         7
                         Algeria         6
                         Andorra         4
       status            Afghanistan    NF
                         Albania        NF
                         Algeria        NF
                         Andorra        PF
dtype: object
```

`Unstack` the series on `level=1` to reshape back to dataframe

```
   years      country civil_liberties political_rights status
0   1972  Afghanistan               5                4     PF
1   1972      Albania               7                7     NF
2   1972      Algeria               6                6     NF
3   1972      Andorra               3                4     NF
4   1973  Afghanistan               6                7     NF
5   1973      Albania               7                7     NF
6   1973      Algeria               6                6     NF
7   1973      Andorra               4                4     PF
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and clear explanation!